# How to run bigglm function for large number of variables

Tags: r, memory-management, bigdata

In `ffbase` (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ffbase/ffbase.pdf) there is the `bigglm` function:

```
bigglm.ffdf(formula, data, family = gaussian(), ...,
```

where `formula` is something like `Y~X`, assuming `Y` and `X` correspond to the `colnames` of `ffdf` object called `data`.

What if I have 200 columns in `data` that I want to put on the RHS of the equation? Clearly I can't type `Y~X1+X2+....+X200`.

How do I run `Y~X1+X2+....+X200` without typing out all 200 variables on the RHS?

Answer (score 5):

the `.` symbol is the normal character for this, not sure if it works with `ffbase` though.  I.e.

```
m <- lm(y ~ ., df)
```

will describe `y` by all other columns in `df`.

As described by Chris, this appears to be a bug in `biglm`, and can be worked around by using:

```
m <- bigglm(terms(y ~ ., data=df), data=df)
```

But this should be reported as a bug to the author of `biglm`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work `Error in terms.formula(formula) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
`

Comment: I'd trying giving it a `data` argument then, i.e. which big data frame are you wanting to grab the "other" columns from

Comment: I run `z <- bigglm(V1~.,data=together)` which gives the error. If I run `z <- bigglm(V1~V2,data=together)` where `V2` is one of the colnames, then it'll work.

Comment: just tried installing the packages, and get the same...  presume it doesn't support this syntax, how annoying.  Try @Christopher's approach.

Comment: @SamMason: I was curious why it wouldn't work to have `Y ~ .` so I looked at the source code.  It turns out that when the author of **ffbase** wrote the `bigglm` function, he didn't pass the `data` argument to the `terms` function.

Comment: Yes, just playing as well.  The OP can put a manual `terms` call around the formula before passing to `bigglm`, will update my answer to show this workaround.

Comment: @SamMason, I just reported the bug to the author of **ffbase**.

Comment: @ChristopherLouden, so have I.  Lets see!

Answer (score 3):

If Sam's answer doesn't work, you can build up a character string representing the formula and then cast is as a formula:

```
formula <- as.formula(paste('Y', paste(paste('', 
       paste('X', 1:200, sep = ''), sep = '', collapse = ' + ')), sep = ' ~ '))
```

The inner `paste` creates `X1` to `X200`.  The next paste collapses the resulting vector into a single string with the elements of the first `paste` put together with +'s.  The last `paste` adds on the `Y ~`.  Finally, I change it from a string to a formula.